# Redirecionamento Autenticado/Não Autenticado

Tags: laravel-5

Quanto protegemos uma rota por login e tentamos acessar essa rota sem estar logado o laravel nos manda para a tela de login. Dai se vc autentica ele manda pra quela rota que vc tentou acessar sem estar logado.

Estou com um problema pois não gostaria que o laravel guardasse essa tentativa de acesso e redirecionamento. Gostaria de saber como tratar isso?

Comment: `Estou com um problema pois não gostaria que o Laravel guardasse essa tentativa de acesso e redirecionamento. Gostaria de saber como tratar isso?` o que você quer fazer?

Comment: Gostaria de controlar isso de forma que só fosse redirecionado pra rota que eu coloquei como rota padrão exemplo. Apos Login vai para /home e boas só isso

Answer (score 1):

O laravel trata isso de diversas formas. A maneira recorrente é a utilização da trait: `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` se você estiver usando a autenticação padrão fornecida pelo framework: `php artisan make:auth`. O Laravel gerou o controlador de login:  `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController` Lá existe a propriedade `protected $redirectTo = '/rotapararedirecionaraposologin'`